# Summations and for loops

Tags: math, loops, sum

I'm having a bad time reading an article, which has lots of formulas. It has several sumatories (I mean like this:  ∑h ∑i) Can I write it as two nested for loops?

Like:

```
for (h=1; h<=5; h++){
    for(i=1; i<=5; i++){
        sum+=i;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your patience :)

Comment: do you mean you have two sets of data and you want to multiply the sums, or do you mean that each h has a corresponding sum of i's

Comment: Somatorio is the portuguese word for Sum.  http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=pt&u=http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somat%25C3%25B3rio&prev=/search%3Fq%3Dsomatorio%26hl%3Den%26biw%3D1186%26bih%3D762%26prmd%3Dimvns&sa=X&ei=-bjpT-T2Boqa8gS357zwDQ&sqi=2&ved=0CEMQ7gEwAA

Comment: This question is off-topic for SO.  If OP (re-)formulates it as a programming question then it will, most likely, be on-topic.

Comment: If you were to implement this on a sequential machine, then yes, this would be equivalent to a nested loop that sums things up. But it is better to think of it as - "the sum of all h, over the sum of all i, where ...". It will probably help your understanding if you try to think functional, rather than procedural. This will also make it easier to parallize, should you decide to implement it.

Comment: I disagree, "how do I turn math into code" seems on-topic to me.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the example 11 [here](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=pt&u=http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somat%25C3%25B3rio&prev=/search?q=somatorio&hl=en&biw=1186&bih=762&prmd=imvns&sa=X&ei=-bjpT-T2Boqa8gS357zwDQ&sqi=2&ved=0CEMQ7gEwAA):

```
 Sum(Sum(x*y)) = Sum(x)*Sum(y)
```

The left side can be written as nested for loops:

```
for(x goes 1 to n)
  for(y goes 1 to m)
    add to the result (x*y)
```

The right side can be written as two independent loops.

```
for(x goes 1 to n)
  add to the firstResult (x)
for(y goes 1 to m)
  add to the secondResult (y)
set result to firstResult * secondResult
```

The right side improves the time efficiency O(n*m) vs O(n+m) but costs some space (to hold on to first and second result).